# How to send POST request with no data

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

Is it possible using `urllib` or `urllib2` to send no data with a `POST` request? Sounds odd, but the API I am using sends blank data in the `POST` request.

I've tried the following, but it seems to be issuing a `GET` request because of no `POST` data.

```
url = 'https://site.com/registerclaim?cid=' + int(cid)
values = {}
headers = {
    'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36',
    'X-CRFS-Token' : csrfToken,
    'X-Requested-With' : 'XMLHttpRequest'   
}

data    = urllib.urlencode(values)
req     = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
resp    = opener.open(req)
```

I am getting a 404 exception, which is what the API returns if trying to access the page via a 'GET' request. I've checked all the variables to ensure they are set correctly, and they are.

Am advice?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.request.html), urllib does not appear to provide an explicit way to set the request type. In a couple of places, it states that the request type is set by the presence or absence of data: "_If the url uses the http: scheme identifier, the optional data argument may be given to specify a POST request (normally the request type is GET)._"

Comment: Something else is wrong. When `data` is an empty string, an empty POST body is sent.

Comment: I will try with an empty string.

Comment: @JamesJeffery: doesn't matter; `data` is already an empty string. Your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins: when `data` is left to the default `None` then `GET` is used. *Anything else* triggers a `POST`; this includes the empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your diagnosis is incorrect; `urllib2` *will* send an empty POST body in your case:

```
>>> import urllib, urllib2
>>> url = 'http://httpbin.org/post?cid=42'
>>> headers = {
...     'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36',
...     'X-CRFS-Token': 'csrf_token_mocked',
...     'X-Requested-With' : 'XMLHttpRequest'   
... }
>>> values = {}
>>> data    = urllib.urlencode(values)
>>> req     = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
>>> req.has_data()
True
>>> req.get_method()
'POST'
>>> resp    = urllib2.urlopen(req)
>>> body = resp.read()
>>> print body
{"args": {"cid": "42"}, "data": "", "files": {}, "form": {}, "headers": {"Accept-Encoding": "identity", "Connection": "close", "Content-Length": "0", "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Host": "httpbin.org", "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36", "X-Crfs-Token": "csrf_token_mocked", "X-Request-Id": "a14f84f5-a355-4b8a-8b34-cb42808b8b09", "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}, "json": null, "origin": "81.134.152.4", "url": "http://httpbin.org/post?cid=42"}
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> import json
>>> pprint(json.loads(body))
{u'args': {u'cid': u'42'},
 u'data': u'',
 u'files': {},
 u'form': {},
 u'headers': {u'Accept-Encoding': u'identity',
              u'Connection': u'close',
              u'Content-Length': u'0',
              u'Content-Type': u'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
              u'Host': u'httpbin.org',
              u'User-Agent': u'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36',
              u'X-Crfs-Token': u'csrf_token_mocked',
              u'X-Request-Id': u'a14f84f5-a355-4b8a-8b34-cb42808b8b09',
              u'X-Requested-With': u'XMLHttpRequest'},
 u'json': None,
 u'origin': u'81.134.152.4',
 u'url': u'http://httpbin.org/post?cid=42'}
```

Some things to note:

- the http://httpbin.org/post route only accepts POST methods; it'll return a 405 response otherwise.
- The `req.get_method()` method is used to determine what method to use when sending the request; you can see that it'll use `POST` even though `values` is empty. `req.get_method()` determines the method used based on the `req.has_data()` response, and *that* method returns `True` when the `data` attribute is not `None`. An empty string qualifies here as having data.
- The http://httpbin.org/post response shows the request headers; the content-length header was set to 0, indicating an empty POST body.

So the question then is: how certain are you you have everything required for the POST to succeed? Perhaps a `Referer` header is required, or perhaps you misunderstood what parameters are passed in and the POST body is *not* meant to be empty.

Comment: I have tested `req.get_method()` and it is sending it as 'POST'. So the problem is somewhere else. Very odd. I will accept your answer though because I couldn't find anything on Google about sending blank `POST` requests and someone else might find this useful.

Comment: The problem was I spelt `X-CRFS-Token` wrong. It took me hours to find that. Surprised no SO user spotted it. Thanks again buddy.

Comment: @JamesJeffery: Heh, and I didn't even notice I spelt it differently from you in the mocked value.. I've written that acronym too many times.